# Autocomplete widget always passes null parameter to the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having a trouble with `JQuery` `Autocomplete` widget. The search parameter is always passing null to the controller. Even the parameters names are equal in view and controller.

Here is my controller:

```
public JsonResult Blist(string term)
{
    try
    {
       var fullPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/BankList.csv");

       List<string> master = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fullPath).ToList();
       master = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fullPath).Where(s => s.Trim() != string.Empty).ToList();

       var rowmaster = (from dr in master

       let parts = dr.Split(",".ToCharArray())

       select new { name = parts[1], code = parts[0] }).ToList();
            PromotersListscs prolist = new PromotersListscs();

            return Json(rowmaster, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Blist", "ControlerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("term", null, new { id = "txtSearch" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />   
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
              source: '@Url.Action("Blist", "ControlerName")',
              minLength: 0
          });
      });
        </script>
```

I tried:

```
@Html.TextBox("term", null, new { id = "txtSearch", formaction = @Url.Action("Blist", "POPM_Ref_PromotersInfo"), formmethod = "Get" })
```

Still passing null.

Comment: Could you check the actual request coming from the browser? you basically use the $.ajax (inside the autocomplete source code) to make a call to the api. So i think that you forgot to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are not passing searchterm to controller action. try this

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ControlerName/Blist",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {    
                    response(data);                    }
            });
        }
    });
});
```